# Visual Studio 2012 Project targeting Windows XP using MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2012, inno-setup, installshield

I have recently acquired source code from a VS2005 project that uses the MFC library. Firstly I upgraded the project to VS2012 and I can now successfully build and run the software on Windows 8. Next, I wanted to deploy the software on a Windows XP machine.

I have set the Platform Toolset to build to Windows XP (using the v110_xp option) and I have installed the 'Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 1' on the target machine. When I run the software, nothing appears to happen. Via some logging functions I can determine that a call to LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME) causes an exception in kernel32.dll. I can't debug any further in to LoadFrame as remote debugging on Windows XP is not available in VS2012.

Any ideas what may be going wrong? Is the Visual C++ Redistributable package the correct version to be installing on the target machine? What should I be trying next?

**UPDATE**

My project is already set up to use the 7.1 SDK and has minimum required version set to 5.01 in linker options.

If I use InstallShield to generate an installer and include the MFC, CRT and ATL redistributables, the installer works and my program now runs on Windows XP. My understanding of the redistributables is that they simply copy the relevant dll's in to the system32 folder (or equivalent)? Is that correct?

However, if I simply copy the files over, run the vsredist_x86.exe or use Inno Setup to install the software & dll's, my program no longer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the working InstallShield project and the not-working Inno project I was able to determine that the real culprit here was an unregistered msxml4.dll. The error I was receiving gave no real clue to this outcome but I got there eventually...

```
regsvr32 msxml4.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have read [this blog](http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/visual-studio-2012-update-1-released-real-official-xp-targeting-support/). In summary, you need to use the 7.1 SDK, and you need to set minimum required version to 5.01 in linker options.